# Display only some form fields in a django model form, based on a dropdown of that same model form?

Tags: javascript, django, forms, modelform

That dropdown field is part of the model. Also, I don't want to reload the form when the dropdown changes.  I'm quite sure this must be done with javascript. I more or less know how I could do it, but wanted to ask if there are any out of the box reusable apps I dont know about that can do what I want?

**For better understanding, some examples:**

Example 1: Have a "Link" model, fields: `type, url, file, etc`. `type` is the dropdown field and defines which field is shown.

Example 2 (advanced): CMS content model "image text", fields `type, title, text, images (inline), video_file, video_preview_image`. Again, `type` is the dropdown and depending on `type`, either the images inline is shown, or the other two fields, `video_file` and `video_preview_image`. `type`, `title` and `text` are always shown.

Comment: instead of voting for closing this, I'm interested WHY it should be closed?

Comment: Didn't vote to close, but it helps a lot to provide code you have tried and where you currently stand

Comment: I don't have any code yet, just the models and the modelform that displays all fields all the time. I'm asking for a reusable app the might do what I want...otherwise I will have to code it myself.

Comment: I voted to close because its unclear what you're asking, How does this dropdown relate to your model form? Where does the dropdown come from? Your two examples aren't really clear to me; hence the vtc.

Comment: I clarified some things: the dropdown field is part of the model form. Depending on the value of the dropdown, some fields are shown, some are hidden.

Comment: anyone? understandable now?